# PHP - Stop need to create hundreds of variables

Tags: php

I'm writing a script and it seems like a bit of a ballache so I came on SO to ask for a little help making my script more dynamic so I create a better version of what I'm doing. I've read into variable variables but I'm still stuck on how I'd use them.

I'll obviously shorten this down but my current script is:

```
$a0 = $tags['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'];
$a1 = $tags['items'][1]['snippet']['tags'];
$a2 = $tags['items'][2]['snippet']['tags'];

if (!is_array($a0)) { $a0 = array(); }
if (!is_array($a1)) { $a1 = array(); }
if (!is_array($a2)) { $a2 = array(); }

$a0 = array_map('strtolower', $a0);
$a1 = array_map('strtolower', $a1);
$a2 = array_map('strtolower', $a2);

array_count_values(array_merge($a0,$a1,$a2));
```

I'm looking for a way to dynamically create the variables (For example using an index in a while loop rather than creating these variables uniquely. This obviously is fine on a small scale, but i've currently done 50 of these for each and it's causing serious time problems. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: my guess would be that instead of trying to optimise your current approach, which apparently isn't working that great, you should think about your process in general and how you could cleanly restructure it so you do not have these problems. as to how to use variable variables: not. they are a huge code smell and best avoided until you know 100% exactly what you are doing - and if you do know, you won't use variable variables.

Comment: This question would be better / more complete with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to produce the same output that you get from `array_count_values` with a nested `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($tags['items'] as $x) {                       // loop over the list of items
    foreach ($x['snippet']['tags'] as $tag) {          // loop over the tags from each item
        $tag = strtolower($tag);
        if (!isset($counts[$tag])) $counts[$tag] = 0;
        $counts[$tag]++;                               // increment the tag count
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($counts as $tag => $count) { echo "$tag: $count<br>"; }`

Comment: That isn't a json object though right?  I could have just declared `json_encode($array, true);` on my last script

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were going for json. Yeah, `json_encode` should work just fine. I don't think it needs a second arg, though.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean how do I use the JSON encode() so it will look the same as my previous array `{ name: value, name: value, name: value }` surely if i encode these in a foreach it wont look like that

Comment: Have you tried `echo json_encode($ counts);`? I think it should produce that output.

Comment: Thank you! It echos the JSON perfectly but gives a small error for me on `foreach ($x['snippet']['tags'] as $tag) { ` this line-  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I assume that means that not every `$x` has `['snippet']['tags']`. You could check `isset($x['snippet']['tags'])` before the inner `foreach` loop to avoid that error.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the whole $tags variable as an array and you can do this, similar to the strtolower array_map you have already:

```
$tagItems = [];
foreach($tags['items'] as $item) {
    if (!$item['snippet']['tags'] || !is_array($item['snippet']['tags'])) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach($item['snippet']['tags'] as $tag) {
        $tag = strtolower($tag);
        if (!isset($tagItems[$tag])) {
            $tagItems[$tag] = 0;
        }
        $tagItems[$tag]++;
    }
}
```

As @FranzGleichmann says, try not to use variable variables, which are a smell and potential security risk, but instead rethink how you want to approach the problem.

Comment: Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Comment: Slightly misunderstood what was meant to happen. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

No need to create 100 variables. That would cause a headache. Instead, use a simple loop function.

```
 $b = array(); 
       for ($n=1; $n<=100; $n++) {
         $a = $tags['items']["$n"]['snippet']['tags'];
         if (!is_array($a)) { $a = array(); }
         $a = array_map('strtolower', $a);
         array_count_values(array_merge($b,$a));
    }
```

I hope it works! Have a nice coding

Answer (score 0):

I would write this in a comment but i will a long one,
Variable Variable, is simply the value of the original `var` assigned as a var name, which means:

```
$my_1st_var = 'im_1st';
//use $$
$$my_1st_var = 'im_2nd'; //that is the same of $im_1st='im_2nd';
//results
echo $my_1st_var; // >>> im_1st
echo $im_1st;     // >>> im_2nd
```

that means i created a new `var` and called it the value of the 1st `var` which is `im_1st` and that makes the variable name is `$im_1st`

also you can set multiple values as a var name:

```
$var0 = 'a';
$var1 = 'b';
$var2 = 'c';
$var3 = '3';
//we can do this
${$var0.$var1} = 'new var 1'; //same as: $ab = 'new var 1';
${$var1.$var2.$var3} = 'im the newest'; //same as: $bc3 = 'im the newest';
//set a var value + text
${$var0.'4'.$var1} = 'new?'; //same as: $a4b = 'new?';
```

also `$GOLBALS[];` is some kind of `$$`

hope it helps you understanding what is hard for you about `$$` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so dynamically creating variables is easy is a script language like PHP.

You could make `$a` an array, and instead of `$a0`, `$a1`, ... use `$a[$i]` where `$i` goes from 0 to 50 or more.

Or you could use this nice funky syntax: `${'a'.$i}`. For example:

```
$i = 0;
${'a'.$i} = 'foobar';
echo $a0; // will output foobar
```

However you shouldn't do any of this.

What you should do is think about what you are trying to achieve and come up with a different algorithm that doesn't require dynamically named variables.

In this case, something like this looks like it would do the job:

```
$result = [];
foreach ( $tags['items'] as $item ) {
  if ( is_array($item['snippet']['tags']) ) {
     $result = array_merge($result, array_map('strtolower',$item));
  }
}
array_count_values($result);
```

This is obviously not tested and from the top of my head, but I hope you get the idea. (EDIT: or check the other answers with similarly rewritten algorithms)

Comment: Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Comment: @ConorReidd Again, not tested and from the top of my head. The point was: rewrite your algorithm, don't try to generate hundreds of variable dynamically.